# How to launch a second webview from a cordova javascript based hybrid app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, 3d-secure

I'm developing a hybrid `cordova`-based application, which runs on both `iOS` and Android devices. In a certain scenario I have to open a `webview` inside the application, in order to complete a credit card payment, with the `3D` Secure platform. Since the `3D` Secure only works via browser, I thought that I could use a `webview` for this purpose, but I don't know how to open one in my app.

My `cordova` version is 3.6.

Comment: You could try using [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin. It allows you to open all external links in a web browser which is explicitly linked with your app.

Comment: Thank you @Fido. I'll let you know if it solves my case!

Comment: I have noticed your edit. Be aware that to be properly secure you should be using at least cordova 4 and using [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) whitelist plugin which allows you to define which external links your app can touch. Without specifying a whitelist your app will disallow loading many external pages.

Comment: I  knew about the whitelist, but the cordova version maybe an issue... :/
Do you know which problem I can find using a lower version of cordova?

Comment: If you using a lower version of cordova and you do not have the whitelist plugin then certain webpages on certain devices will just refuse to load. For example on Android 5.0.1 no whitelist-plugin and an old version of cordova means no external pages will load even if you have allowed `origins=http://*` in your config.xml.